# Query optimizer index selection on compound index when querying only by the second field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-indexes

Suppose I have a [compound index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#compound-indexes) `{ a: 1, b: 1 }`.

The query `db.Collection.find( { b: 1 } )` doesn't use this index. The [query optimizer](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations/#read-operations-query-optimization) does not appear to select this index as a candidate run.

However if you specifically `hint` the index, the query runs much faster and the `nscan` is much lower:

`db.Collection.find( { b: 1 } ).hint( { a: 1, b: 1 } )`

My question is, if using the index results in a faster query, ***why would the [query optimizer](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations/#read-operations-query-optimization) ignore the index in my query on `b` alone?***

Comment: can you share the actual explain() output? what are the collection stats, what are nscanned values in both cases?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky without hint `nscan` = 2M (full table scan). With the hint `nscan` = 2K. Interestingly, `a` has about 1K unique values, so the `nscan` is about 2x the selectivity of `a` when using the index.

Comment: From the page you link to on "compound index": "Compound indexes support queries on any prefix of the fields in the index."  The case where an index helps on a query that is not a prefix is very rare, and has something to do with the distribution of values `a` (maybe it has very few possible values?).  The optimal thing to do in that case is to not try using an index, because that could make things slower.

Answer (score 2):

From the page you link to on "compound index": "Compound indexes support queries on any prefix of the fields in the index." The case where an index helps on a query that is not a prefix is fairly specific, and has something to do with the distribution of values of `a` (I believe it does a better job as the number of possible values of `a` decreases). The optimal thing to do in that case is to not try using an index, because that could make things slower.

In the comments, you suggest that it shouldn't be very much slower in the worst case, but could give large improvements. Well, let's try a little testing. I built a collection with 10^6 documents, where each document `i` is `{a: i, b: i+1}`.  This is, in my hypothesis, the worst case for a query on only `b` when using the index `{a: 1, b: 1}`.

For the query

```
db.testing.find({b: 0}).explain()
```

we find that it scanned 1,000,000 documents (not surprising) in about 350ms.  Not bad for an unindexed query.  Now, let's hint that index:

```
db.testing.find({b: 0}).hint("a_1_b_1").explain()
```

This time it only scanned 954,546 documents.  I don't know enough about MongoDB indexes to explain this.  However, this slightly smaller scan took about 2300ms, or 6.5x as long as the unindexed query.

So yes, a poorly-indexed query can be *much* worse than an unindexed one.  But this doesn't completely answer your question - why doesn't the query optimizer figure this out?

The query optimizer runs different plans in parallel the first time it sees a query, and remembers the best for future queries (this is occasionally re-evaluated).  But, it will only try candidate indexes - that is, those where some non-empty prefix of the index matches some portion of the query.  By this standard, of course, `{a: 1, b: 1}` is not a candidate index for a query on just `b`.

I would suggest either creating a second index on `{b: 1}` (or at least with that prefix), or reversing the order of the one you already have (create `{b: 1, a: 1}` and then drop the old one).

Comment: Thanks. Do you think it would make more sense to change the rule for candidate indexes to include all indexes where the field is present, rather than the prefixed ones? (By the way the prefix rule isn't quite implemented the way it's written in the doc... see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053201/mongo-triple-compound-index))

Comment: the question(answer) you linked to is from a year ago - version 2.0 of MongoDB.  There were several optimizations/fixes to query optimization in 2.2 and 2.4 some of which would have changed some small parts of the (excellent) answer given there.  But the bottom line is still the same - B-tree organization is such that later parts of the index have only limited use when you don't use equality on prior parts of the index.

Comment: @ZaidMasud I made an edit that I hope makes it clearer.  I suppose I was rather ambiguous about it originally.

Answer (score 0):

Compound index are generally used, for prefix matched queries, or full matched ones.

Clearly your first query don't qualify. You don't need to provide a hack for this. Instead you can just hint the optimiser to use the { a : 1, b : 1 } index

```
db.Collection.find({ b: 1 }).hint({ a:1, b:1 })
```

Comment: Yes I'm aware of this. My question is why doesn't this happen by default? Hints should only be required to override the query optimizer's selection. I've clarified my question to phrase it from the perspective of the query optimizer.

Comment: This query will do a complete index scan, thus whole index fetch from disk and and then actual documents fetch which may turn out to no optimizations using index in many use cases. So, I guess, BasicCursor was preferred. The first query may be faster, if used index then doing collection scan, but it depends.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a phone book that is organized by "Last name, First name" but you only had a first name, do you think the phone book would help you find the person you were searching for?

That's what you are trying to force the optimizer to do when you have an index on a, b and you are selecting on b.  It means for every value of a it needs to look and see if b matches.

There are many possible reasons why using this index may be faster than a collection scan *in some circumstances*.  In general, it's not a candidate index and you should not use this as a solution to speeding up queries on `b`.

The way [the current version's MongoDB query optimizer works](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations/#read-operations-query-optimization) is it tries the query with multiple query plans (all *candidate* indexes plus collection scan).  Whichever is fastest "wins", the others are terminated and the winning plan is cached for some period of time.  If you run `db.collection.find(...).explain(true) you will actually see all the "plans" it has tried.  If the index is not considered a candidate then it won't be in the mixed for this phase - the only way to get the query to use it would be to explicitly "hint" it.

The query optimizer will be changing in the next major release so the above applies to the state of the world in 2.4 and earlier versions.

Comment: I understand that and this was the reason given in Kyle's cookbook example as well. But in your phone book scenario, don't you think that using the index will still result in scanning fewer documents than doing a full table scan, no matter what the data distribution? What I am saying is I don't visualize why it'll be faster in *some* circumstances. What's an example where it'll be slower?

Comment: I don't think so.  I think it would depend on a lot of things, main one among them the selectivity of a values.  If a can only be (say) true or false it would be a lot faster.  if a has thousands of values I don't think it would help much at all...  In any case, it's the wrong strategy for query optimization to count on this.

Comment: A non-multi-key index, by definition, can never have more entries than the collection. Therefore using the index can never by slower than a full table scan. Even if it was slower as you seem to be believe is possible, why shouldn't it be a candidate for the query optimizer? That's supposed to be the whole point of the query optimizer... run different candidates and select the fastest one.

Comment: @ZaidMasud "using the index can never by slower than a full table scan"...unless traversing the index takes time.  Which seems awfully likely.  I suspect that this is so rarely a good choice for the query optimizer that 10gen decided never to try it.

Comment: @AaronDufour nitpicking here but I actually mean "using the index can never scan more documents than a full table scan." Which is really the main thing to look for in terms of magnitude `O(n)`... index traversal overhead is considered negligible in the big scheme of things.

Comment: You are comparing two "bad" things (scanning the wrong index and scanning full collection) - why not create and use a "good" index for the query?

Comment: @ZaidMasud seriously? Downvoting an answer because you don't like the way things work?  Why did you even ask the question?

Comment: @ZaidMasud Feel free to read my answer, in which I show that the index traversal overhead is anything but negligible.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky yes creating a good index is ideal. But the only question here was why it makes sense to ignore the given index for the query optimizer. I've downvoted because I think you're answering a different question than the one that's been asked. I've explained the reasons and this is perfectly reasonable SO etiquette. It has nothing to do with not liking how things work. If you edit your answer I'm happy to remove the downvote.

Comment: added explanation of query optimizer (with link) and why it doesn't try your index.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky thanks, removed the downvote. Did you have some feedback on why you've downvoted the question? If not clear then I'm happy to provide any additional details to clarify what I'm asking.